# Refresh JWT tokens on each request

Tags: docusignapi

I'm setting up a document esigning process using Docusign. Since we have multiple associations, We have setup multiple accounts (around 20 APIAccountID under one organization (or you can say as one INTEGRATOR_KEY_ID)) one for each association. Can someone please let me know on how do we switch to different APIAccountID based on the request we get. Also, is it the right way to create a new DocuSignConnection every time when we get the request for different association ?

Answer (score 1):

Your integration should use just one `INTEGRATOR_KEY` for the entire integration.  When using one of the [DocuSign OAuth flows](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication) such as JWT as you mention.

After the user grants access by providing their credentials and clicking `Accept` an access token will be sent back to your app (at the redirect URI you specify on your integrator key).

You then use that access token to call the [User Info API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints) which will return account ID for that given user.

**User Info API**

Request:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX...MrhIddzBAQ

GET https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo
```

Response:

```
{
  "sub": "4799e5e9-1559-4915-9862-cf4713bbcacc",
  "name": "Susan Smart",
  "given_name": "Susan",
  "family_name": "Smart",
  "created": "2015-08-13T22:03:03.45",
  "email": "susan.smart@example.com",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "account_id": "a4ec37d6-04aa-4f37-86c2-143885c220e1",
      "is_default": true,
      "account_name": "Susan Smart",
      "base_uri": "https://domain.example.com",
      "organization": {
        "organization_id": "9c5fb8e1-b0bf-4970-8e0e-054ff8a249bf",
        "links": [
          {
            "rel": "self",
            "href": "https://account.domain.example.com/organizations/9c5fb8e1-b0bf-4970-8e0e-054ff8a249bf"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one application which sends signing requests on behalf of multiple associations (organizations)?

As Ergin says, your application will have one integration key which will be used for all associations.

When a human logs into you app using OAuth Auth Code Grant, your app receives an access token. You can use that access token to look up the user's account and site (API URL).

Your application can make sending requests for any number of people and their associations. Each API request includes the user's individual access token, their account_id, and uses the site data to create the URL.

HTH.